# Is turbulence due to the inertia of the fluid?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, turbulence

[Turbulence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbulence) is the time-dependent chaotic behavior seen in many fluid flows.

Why is it generally believed that turbulence is due to the [inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertia) of the fluid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is the [Reynolds number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number),
$$
Re=\frac{\rho LV}{\mu}=\frac{LV}{\nu}\tag{1}
$$
where $L$ and $V$ are characteristic lengths and velocities of the particular problem and $\mu$ & $\nu$ are the dynamic & kinematic [viscosities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity), respectively.

If you multiply (1) by $\rho LV/\rho LV$, you get
$$
Re=\frac{\rho L^2V^2}{\mu LV}
$$
The numerator is the inertial force while the denominator is the viscous force. When $Re$ is small, the fluid flow is described as [Laminar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laminar_flow). When $Re$ is large, the fluid flow is described as turbulent. Since $Re$ is large for large inertial force (relative to the viscous force), we can say that inertia causes turbulence.

However, [elastic turbulence](http://math.unice.fr/~musacchi/tesi/node46.html) in liquid polymers can occur when $Re$ is small, suggesting that the cause$\leftrightarrow$effect from above may not actually be correct, at least for the case of polymers.

Comment: Perhaps I am mistaken here, but I am confused as to why it is thought inertia matters.  I ask because according to your equation, R$_{e}$ $\rightarrow$ $\infty$ for $\mu$ $\rightarrow$ 0, right?  However, without viscosity can a fluid be turbulent?  I thought superfluids always exhibited laminar flows?  Did I miss something?

Comment: Superfluids are not your typical (classical) fluid, much like the liquid polymer case I cite; however they do [exhibit turbulent flows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_turbulence).

Comment: If you check the viscosity link in the body (to the Wiki page), you'll see an animation of two flows in which the only difference is viscosity; the lower viscosity fluid exhibits more turbulence than the higher viscosity flow.

Comment: Ah, I see now why I was confused.  I was aware of the quantized eddies/vortices, but I thought that implied a lack of turbulence since the eddies are all of the same size (and predictable), not random.  I was also confused by the fact that if you managed to create a macroscopic eddy in a superfluid, I was under the impression that the eddy would remain the same size so long as the fluid remained a superfluid condensate.  I thought that turbulence implied a transfer of energy from large-to-small scales through irreversible (viscous) interactions.